# Как починить conditional jump?

Tags: c, память, valgrind

При проверке через valgrind вылазит conditional jump. Предположительно ошибка возникает в функции input, но я не знаю как починить.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct Item {
    int data; 
    struct Item* next;
} Item;

typedef struct Queue{ 
    Item* head;
    Item* tail;
} Queue;


void input(Queue* list,int* stroka) {
     Item* new = (Item*)malloc(sizeof(Item));
    new->data = *stroka;
    new->next = NULL;
    if (!list->head) {
        list->head = new;
        list->tail = new;
    } else {
        list->tail->next = new;
        list->tail = new;
    }
}  
  
void print(const Queue* list) {
    Item* ptr = list->head;
    while(ptr) {
        printf("%c", ptr->data);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}


  int main() {
    int stroka;
    Queue* list = (Queue*)malloc(sizeof(Queue));
    stroka = '"';
    input(list, &stroka);
    while(stroka != EOF) {
        stroka = getchar();
        if (stroka == EOF) {
            stroka = '"';
            input(list, &stroka);
            break;
        }
        input(list, &stroka);
    }
    printf("\n");
    print(list);
}
```

```
  Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==29969==    at 0x10931A: input ()
==29969==    by 0x1093CF: main ()
==29969==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==29969==    at 0x48427B5: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==29969==    by 0x1093B1: main ()
```

Comment: Ключевые слова в ошибке не "conditional jump" (условный переход), а "uninitialised value" (неинициализированная переменная). Нужно смотреть, где у вас в коде в if или while, например, используются неинициализированные переменные.

Comment: @insolor я не совсем понимаю где может быть проблема,  в if я передаю инициализированные переменные

Comment: `Queue* list = (Queue*)malloc(sizeof(Queue));` `Queue`  создается с не инициализированными `head`, `tail`.